# Rails setup method troubleshoot. Test @response does not match actual format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to test an array of images that I've used with css_select to determine if they have the correct format http/https. On the actual production website, I have 30 images that need to be selected. When I run my rake test, I puts the @response.body generated from the setup method but I don't get the exact rendering template. Instead of 30 images I only capture 1 image. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
 require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

 # Re-raise errors caught by the controller.
 class AboutController; def rescue_action(e) raise e end; end

 class AboutControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   fixtures :accounts, :kudos

   def setup
     @controller = AboutController.new
     @request    = ActionController::TestRequest.new
     @response   = ActionController::TestResponse.new
   end



   def test_index_attachments_protocol
     get :home
     puts @response.body
     assert_response :success
     css_select(".top_ten_row .top_ten_icon img").each  do |anchor|

       assert_match anchor["src"], /http:/
     end
     #grab everything else besides the above image
   end
```

Is the reason that the images are not being captured because of the test database? Additionally, the images captured don't have an http or https associated with them. The format only shows as such

`src="/attachments/0000/0001/test_logo_small.png`

Is this also a result of the test database?

Finally, I'm using Rails 2.3. I would like to update but I can't because the app I'm working on hasn't been updated in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use the image_tag with a **relative path**, not a **full path** (protocol + domain + relative_path).

- Configure your `config.action_controller.asset_host` to the relevant value,

or

- use `image_url`:

  ```
  image_url("rails.png")
  # => "http://www.example.com/assets/rails.png"
  ```

---

References:

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @MrYoshiji. I saw the doc and that helps the http problem. Would you happen to know why the response isn't the same though? Just to be clear, not only were the http/https not included, but some images were not even in the html itself. Would you happen to know why off the top of your head?

Comment: No I don't, I never used tests like this (testing HTML presence). If the amount of images is dynamic (coming from your DB), then make sure you have these images existing in your test Database